# Is there a Shoulda matcher for validates_uniqueness_of(:attribute) with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm creating a Course app with chapters and quizzes. An admin can create a quizz by adding questions and answers. I want to apply a business rule so that a question can only have one answer with the `is_correct` attribute set to 'true'

Therefore I added a validation callback to my Answer model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :is_correct, conditions: -> { where(is_correct: true) }
```

This works, but I also want to test it with Rspec and Shoulda matchers.

I looked up the information for Shoulda matchers at:
http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames

but there is nowhere a instruction how to define a Shoulda matcher for

```
validates_uniqueness_of(:is_correct) with the attribute value set to true
```

Is there a way to define this with a Shoulda matcher?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Shoulda matchers are actually remarkably extensive, but it took a little while to find some of the extras. Check out this site: http://travisonrails.com/2013/02/20/shoulda-matcher-model-extras

```
describe Answer do
  context 'validations' do
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:is_correct) }
  end
end
```